# Concatenate two strings elements wise

Tags: python, string, string-concatenation

I came across a problem in which i had to concatenate two string element wise
for ex :

```
str1 = "ABCD"
str2 = "EFGH"
output = "AEBFCGDH"
```

I wrote this code

```
op = ''
op = op.join([i + j for i, j in zip(str1, str2)])
print(op)
```

And it worked but I was wondering if the length of two strings is different
for ex:

```
str1 = "ABC"
str2 = "DEFGH"
output = "ADBECFGH"

or

str1 = "ABCDG"
str2 = "DEF"
output = "ADBECFDG"
```

How do I code for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the shorter string, zip until its length and then concatenate the remaining part of the longer string.
eg:

```
str1 = 'ABC'
str2 = 'DEFGH'
op = ''
if len(str1)>len(str2):
    op = op.join([i + j for i, j in zip(str1, str2)])+str1[len(str2):]
else:
    op = op.join([i + j for i, j in zip(str1, str2)]) + str2[len(str1):]
print(op) # output: ADBECFGH
```

zip() only zips until the shorter of the two iterables.
See: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 1):

Just switch `zip()` with `zip_longest()`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
str1 = "ABCDG"
str2 = "DEF"
output = ''.join([i + j for i, j in zip_longest(str1, str2, fillvalue="")])
print(output)  # ADBECFDG
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution:

```
str1 = "ABCDG"
str2 = "DEF"
suffix_start = min(len(str1), len(str2))
suffix = str1[suffix_start:]+str2[suffix_start:]
output = ''.join([i + j for i, j in zip(str1, str2)]) + suffix
print(output)  # ADBECFDG
```

Comment: Why the -1 though?